# rake gems:install shows error (database is not migrating)/

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

1. **Ruby: 1.8.7**
2. **Rails: 2.3.8**
3. **Db: my SQL**

---

The database is created but When I migrate database it shows error. so if any one can help me out with this issue so it's fine for me.

---

```
$ rake db:migrate
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/active_record_tableless/tasks, vendor/plugins/annotate-models/tasks, vendor/plugins/asset_auto_include/tasks, vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/tasks, vendor/plugins/jrails/tasks, vendor/plugins/sitemap_generator-plugin/tasks, vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/tasks, and vendor/plugins/tiny_mce/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
rake aborted!
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/client_parser.rb:3: invalid regular expression; there's no previous pattern, to which '{' would define cardinality at 1: /{\w\w\w}/
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/client_parser.rb:44: invalid regular expression; there's no previous pattern, to which '{' would define cardinality at 2: /^{...}/
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder.rb:2
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass.rb:1
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:215:in `load'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/aspireedge/Aspiree/***********/config/environment.rb:15
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

is also show error when I start the server. so if any one can help me out with this issue so it's fine for me.

```
    $ruby script/server 
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/client_parser.rb:3: invalid regular expression; there's no previous pattern, to which '{' would define cardinality at 1: /{\w\w\w}/ (SyntaxError)
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/client_parser.rb:44: invalid regular expression; there's no previous pattern, to which '{' would define cardinality at 2: /^{...}/
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder.rb:2
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass.rb:1
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:215:in `load'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/aspireedge/Aspiree/************/config/environment.rb:15
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/******/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

When I CHange the code of **Client_phaser.rb**.

```
    rake db:migrate
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/active_record_tableless/tasks, vendor/plugins/annotate-models/tasks, vendor/plugins/asset_auto_include/tasks, vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/tasks, vendor/plugins/jrails/tasks, vendor/plugins/sitemap_generator-plugin/tasks, vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/tasks, and vendor/plugins/tiny_mce/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)

rake aborted!
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:50: odd number list for Hash
        o1: build_offer(request.primary_offer),
           ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
        o1: build_offer(request.primary_offer),
           ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:52: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
        v: Config::MSG_VERSION,
          ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:52: dynamic constant assignment
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
        cb: request.callback
           ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:66: odd number list for Hash
        rid: offer.resource.rid,
            ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
        rid: offer.resource.rid,
            ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:67: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
        rnm: offer.resource.name,
            ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:68: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
        rurl: offer.resource.url,
             ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:69: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
        pos: build_price_options(offer.pricing.price_options),
            ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:69: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:71: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:91: odd number list for Hash
        price: price_option.price || '',
              ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
        price: price_option.price || '',
              ^
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:92: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/json_msg_builder.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder.rb:4
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass.rb:1
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:215:in `load'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/aspireedge/Aspiree/pyromaniac/config/environment.rb:78
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@pyro/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: do as shown in error `set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false ` . You have answer in your question :)

Comment: so i put this code in my application.rb?

Comment: I already put this but still got same error and warning too

Comment: its syntax error :) in client_parser.rb:3

Comment: there is no such file name client_parser.rb :)

Comment: The error is related to some tinypass gem configuration. maybe something is not set properly or some data is missing (invalid regular expression)

Comment: exactly I remove that gem and reinstall it again but error still come :)

Comment: The issue is with Gem. Open the [source code](https://rubygems.org/gems/tinypass/versions/1.0.1) and check the line number where you get error. There is a regex `/{\w\w\w}/` which gives error in `Ruby 1.8.7`. I think you need to reach out the developer of gem(check gemspec) to understand the purpose and then you can modify it to make it work.

Comment: actually, tiny pass gem is used for payment's and I setup project before 2 days ago. usually, i used to work with rails 3 + versions.

Comment: Can you please share your config/environment.rb, specifically line 15?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in tinypass gem. The [README](https://github.com/tinypass/ruby-sdk/blob/master/README.md) states that that gem requires Ruby 1.9.2 or above.

There are three options available:

1. Find a version of tinypass compatible with ruby 1.8.7 version .
2. Fork this gem and implement support for older rubies.
3. Update your application to use newer Ruby.

Comment: I feel your pain! Thus, forking looks like the only solution.

Comment: Thanks @itsnikolay for your time but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in regexp

Try to use my fork with a fix:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'tinypass',
 :git    => 'https://github.com/itsNikolay/ruby-sdk.git',
 :branch => 'fix-regexp'
```

And try to run migrations again

Comment: hey, I used  Ruby: 1.8.7, Rails: 2.3.8, Db: my SQL and I saw your repo is for Ruby 1.9.2 or above. BTW Thanks @itsnikolay for your time but still getting the same error.

Comment: @RonakBhatt try to edit files manually like I did https://github.com/tinypass/ruby-sdk/commit/eef7a49b8df073d3af083f1e4652cd414b8e244c 
the files is located under `/home/aspireedge/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-**********/****/tinypass-1.0.1/lib/tinypass/builder/client_parser.rb`

Comment: it shows some error bro :). which I put on the question

Comment: @itsnikolay you have to bump version number to be able to install your fork when latest version of tinypass already installed.